# Find object with specific value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an **array** of **objects** like this:

```
"users": [
   {
     "type": "User",
     "userId": "5b774905c2b2ac0f33ac4cc7",
     "name": "Mike"
   },
   {
     "type": "User",
     "userId": "5b77490f3084460f2986bd25",
     "name": "Pater"
   }
]
```

Now, I would like to check if my array contains an object with the name "Mike".

How do I go about this in javascript?

I am thinking something like this, but not sure how:

```
if ( "Mike" in users ) {
   // Do something...
}
```

Hoping for help on this, and thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate per se, as I'm having a similar problem where the key is numerical and not a string.

Comment: @WayneSmallman there are no numeric keys. The key in `obj = { 1: "hello" }` is converted to a string. There is no difference between `obj[1]` and `obj["1"]`, both refer to exactly the same property. Since numeric keys are just coerced to numbers, there is no special handling for those. Nothing beyond [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406) is needed - `obj.1` is not valid, so it has to use bracket notation. However, that's not intrinsically tied to searching for objects, just regular thing in all property access.

Answer (score 15):

There are many ways to implement that, for example, here are four ES6 methods for that:

1. [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will return `true` or `false`, depending on the condition. It tests, does at list one element fits the condition
2. [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will return an item itself (the first matched item), if the condition evaluates to `true`, and `undefined` if it evaluates to `false`.
3. [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) will return an index of the item (the first matched index), if the condition evaluates to `true`, and `-1` if it evaluates to `false`
4. [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will create a new array with all items, which fit the condition (otherwise it returnes an empty array)

```js
const users = [
   {
     "type": "User",
     "userId": "5b774905c2b2ac0f33ac4cc7",
     "name": "Mike"
   },
   {
     "type": "User",
     "userId": "5b77490f3084460f2986bd25",
     "name": "Pater"
   }
];

const someObject = users.some(item => item.name === 'Mike');
const targetObject = users.find(item => item.name === 'Mike');
const targetIndex = users.findIndex(item => item.name === 'Mike');
const filteredObjects = users.filter(item => item.name === 'Mike');

console.log('someObject:', someObject)
console.log('targetObject:', targetObject)
console.log('targetIndex:', targetIndex)
console.log('filteredObjects:', filteredObjects)
```

Comment: this should be the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

`users.find(user => user.name ==='Mike')`

or

`users.filter(user => user.name ==='Mike').length !== 0`

or

`users.map(user => user.name).includes('Mike')`

Answer (score 1):

```js
if(users.find(({ name }) => name === "Mike")) {
    // do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is the job for the task. It returns `true` or `false` based on if the value exists according to the callback.

```js
let users = [
   {
     "type": "User",
     "userId": "5b774905c2b2ac0f33ac4cc7",
     "name": "Mike"
   },
   {
     "type": "User",
     "userId": "5b77490f3084460f2986bd25",
     "name": "Pater"
   }
]


console.log(users.some(i => i.name == 'Mike'))
console.log(users.some(i => i.name == 'Joe'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value of the property `name` of the inner objects.

This proposal checks every object, because it is not granted, that `name` is unique.

```js
var users = [{ type: "User", userId: "5b774905c2b2ac0f33ac4cc7", name: "Mike" }, { type: "User", userId: "5b77490f3084460f2986bd25", name: "Pater" }];

users.forEach(o => {
    if (o.name === 'Mike') {
        console.log(o);
    }
});
```